# React hook inside promise not even triggered! not log anything?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

why this code doesnt work?
i create this custom hook to call hook useState:

```
 export const useAnimer=({})=>{
    const [animList, setAnimList] = useState({})
    useEffect(()=>{

    .......

    onDone:(anim,name)=>{
      console.log("anim list updating...")
      
      setAnimList((a)=>{
      console.log("anim list updated",a)

      return a
    })}

    ........
    },[depedency])}
```

it's only print

> console.log("anim list updating")

but never print

> console.log("anim list updated")

here where onDone is used in anotherfile.js. it's called every 100ms inside asnyc function that returned promise object

```
  const animIt = async (frame)=>{
      while(true){
        frame.pools.timepassed+=100
          frame.pools.frames.forEach((a,i)=>{ 
              a.onDone(a)           
          })
           await new Promise(resolve=>
            setTimeout(()=>{
              resolve()
            },100))
        
        }
       }
        
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

first, you cannot use hooks in this way `a[name]=anim` you can add new values to object like this {...a,[name]:anim} and then add it to your state : `setAnimList({...a,[name]:anim})`

second, if I were you I would define Arrow function and return it, something like this:

```
export const useAnimer=({})=> {
const [animList, setAnimList] = useState({})

const handleAddAnim = (anim, name) => {
    setAnimList({...animList, [name]: anim})
}

return {
    animList,
    handleAddAnim
}
```

}

and whenever I want to use it i would call it in this way :

```
const {animList, handleAddAnim} = useAnimer();
```

hope I'm helpful

Comment: sorry... i edit the question. i dont care about any value inside setAnimList. what i dont understand is `console.log("anim list updated")` is never called

Comment: I got it, I think the way that you are using useEffect cause problem have you tried to add parentheses to return your object , sth like this :    useEffect(() => ({

        onDone:(anim,name)=>{
            console.log("anim list updating...")

            setAnimList((a)=>{
                console.log("anim list updated",a)

                return a
            })}
    }), []);

please let me know if you could fix it

Comment: `doSomething({
onDone:(anim,name)=>{
  
  setAnimList((a)=>{
  console.log("anim list updated",a)
  return a
})`
on done is actually a callback function that will be called later inside promise